# how to order vyatta HA via JAVA API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, high-availability

How can I order vyatta HA via JAVA API?

i implemented this step.

(After i ordered single vyatta appliance, to upgrading vyatta to HA is done.)

And I would like to order vyatta and HA as one order.

how to configure HA option for order ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not have idea how you are ordening, but I guess your error is that in your order you are setting "quantity=1" for HA you need to set "quantity=2" and in the hardware section you need to set the names and domain for both servers here a JSON e.g.

```
"hardware": [
        {
            "hostname": "vyattagw",
            "domain": "test.com"
        },
        {
            "hostname": "vyattagw2",
            "domain": "test.com"
        }
    ]
```

That's all

Comment: Nice If you can please mark the answer as the correct thank you very much